# How can I connect jdbc connector to MySql databse server?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, jdbc

I get this strange error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

I already tried to reinstall mysql but this was useless. Internet permissions are already in the manifest file.

[this the screen of the code and the actual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYl8m.png)

[this is the code in the "onCreate" function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22w4s.png)

Comment: Please add the error message in text form and provide some more context - what have you tried on your own to spot the error?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling the function to connect your code.?

Comment: it' s ery simple... just the "onCreate" function with an instance of DBConeect class

Comment: well, try calling the function from the background thread. Show the code of the activity and i'll guide you through. @AndreaCominelli

Comment: ok, now i upload a new screenshot

Comment: You really should not connect to a database using JDBC from an android device.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by that localhost (if running on a real device, local host means that device).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Try the below steps.

**Step1:**

Make an inner class in your activity as:

```
private class LoadDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        DBConnect connection = new DBConnect();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Step2:**

Call this in your `onCreate()` as shown below:

```
new LoadDatabase().execute()
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Nope... i still get this error: "Error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure"

Comment: `MySQLNonTransientConnectionException` is solved as asked in the question. To solve the communication exception, try writing the entire connectivity code inside the AsyncTask. @AndreaCominelli

Comment: i tried right now, but it does not help.

Comment: @AndreaCominelli can you post a screenshot of what you tried.

Comment: ok, now posting